# dialog - user input must be alphanumeric and an underscore only

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am using dialog to take some inputs from the user to variables, my problem that in my current script users can enter any values which cause problems. So I would like to put rules for the input to have only alphanumeric and an underscore.

```
#!/bin/sh
# The Dialog Menu
while true; do
  menu="$(dialog --title "bhyve" --backtitle "bhyve, the BSD hypervisor" \
          --stdout --nocancel --menu "Select your OS:" 0 0 0 \
          1 "FreeBSD 12.2" 2 "Exit")"
  if [ "${menu}" -eq 1 ]; then
    while true; do
      if dialog --title "FreeBSD" --stdout --nocancel --inputbox "The VM name:" 0 0 FreeBSD \
          --and-widget --title "FreeBSD" --nocancel --inputbox "RAM (GB):" 0 0 8 \
          --and-widget --title "FreeBSD" --nocancel --inputbox "CPUs:" 0 0 2 \
          --and-widget --title "FreeBSD" --nocancel --inputbox "Disk size (GB):" 0 0 32 > output.txt; then
      name="$(< output.txt awk '{print $1}')"
      ram="$(< output.txt awk '{print $2}')"
      cpu="$(< output.txt awk '{print $3}')"
      disk="$(< output.txt awk '{print $4}')"
      vmd="/zroot/VMs"
      freebsd_iso="/zroot/VMs/ISOs/FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso"
      if [ ! -d "${vmd}" ]; then
        dialog --title "bhyve" --backtitle "bhyve, the BSD hypervisor" \
        --msgbox "/zroot/VMs directory does not exist, please run Setup first" 5 65
        rm output.txt
        exit
      elif [ ! -f "${freebsd_iso}" ]; then
        #pkg install ca_root_nss
        fetch -o /zroot/VMs/ISOs https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/12.2/FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
      elif [ -f "/usr/local/etc/rc.d/${name}" ]; then
      dialog --title "bhyve" --backtitle "bhyve, the BSD hypervisor" \
        --msgbox "The VM ${name} already exists, please choose another name" 5 65
        break;
      fi
      freebsd > /dev/null 2>&1
      dialog --title "bhyve" --backtitle "bhyve, the BSD hypervisor" \
        --msgbox "The VM ${name} has been created" 0 0
        rm output.txt
      else
        rm output.txt
        break;
      fi
    done
  elif [ "${menu}" -eq 2 ]; then
    dialog --title "bhyve" --backtitle "bhyve, the BSD hypervisor" \
    --no-label "Yes" --yes-label "No" \
      --yesno "Would you like to exit?" 0 0
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
      break;
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Given that you're using awk in your script, the obvious choice is to filter the user's input through awk to validate it (and return to the dialog for input when that doesn't validate).